# Value is not posting in a .jsp page

Tags: forms, jsp, post

This is the code that I have for the page that I'm testing out:

Don't worry the startpage and endpage code works.

```
<% startpage(out); %>

<%
String newusers = request.getParameter("users");
int i = 0;
if (newusers != null){
    while(i<10)
               {
    out.println("<h2>newusers</h2>");
    i++;
    }
}
%>

<form action="guestAdder.jsp" method=post>
    <textarea name=users rows=20 cols=100>
    </textarea>
    <p>
        <input type=submit name=doadd value="Add Users">
</form>
<% endpage(out); %>
```

it is a HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/guestAdder_jsp (wrong name: org/apache/jsp/guestadder_jsp)

Comment: Did you try cleaning? Did you rename the JSP page at some point? The change in capitalization is suspicious. That's a scary looking JSP page, btw.

Comment: Don't worry, it's just testing out some stuff. I've never done work with .jsp before so I'm just getting used to how the value posting works.

Comment: I'd still recommend following proper methodology, even when just testing, but that's just me.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on that?

Comment: "Put Java in servlets, classes, and utilities; put markup in JSP." There you go :)

Comment: I got it working! Dunno what I did wrong but hopefully I'll find out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've renamed your jsp file from guestadder.jsp to guestAdder.jsp. Are you on Windows (which isn't case sensitive for filenames)? Looks like the servlet class generated from the JSP page is overwriting the old lowercase-named file but the file isn't being renamed, i.e it is keeping its old name of guestadder_jsp.class

Clear the directory used to cache the servlet classes generated from JSPs - in Tomcat this is tomcat/work